# Transform String in Group by to True / False

Tags: sql

I have a column with different references like this:

```
| ID | REFERENCE |
| 1  | QWERTY    |
| 2  | null      |
| 3  | null      |
| 4  | QWERTY2   |
| 5  | QWERT3    |
```

I need a Group by that divide if the REFERENCE column has value or not.

In this example the result of the group by would like is 3 with REFERENCE and 2 without.

How could I create a group by based on boolean text (exists text or null option)?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select (case when reference is null then 'No reference' else 'Has reference' end) as grp,
       count(*)
from t
group by (case when reference is null then 'No reference' else 'Has reference' end);
```